# Force voice typing on Jellybean?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to force voice typing on Android? I do not mean Speech to Text via the VoiceRecognizer intent, but the new Voice Typing feature that occurs when you hit the keyboard microphone icon.

I read this blogpost which came out pre JellyBean but talks about integrating voicetyping with an IME. I researched IMEs, and the problem with them appears to be that users have to set them system wide, and that won't work for my use case.

I want to be able to force voice typing; instead of the soft keyboard popping up, I'd prefer the voice keyboard.

Thanks,
John